# Share data from generated HTML to React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

I have existing PHP application,
I want to create rich component with React.

In my application I don't have api to React integration, I think the easiest way could be just print data from PHP to HTML as JSON and load this data from React.

For illustration:

```
<?php $data = ..some data loaded from DB.. ?>
<div id="react-component-root" data="<?= json($data) ?>">
```

Question is: What is the best solution to share data from PHP generated HTML to React?

Best = easy and working

Comment: React is written in JavaScript. Your react code is JavaScript also so parsing a JSON string is done with: 
var myObject = JSON.parse('<?php echo $data; ?>');

Comment: What benefits are you trying to get with React?

Comment: @xDreamCoding I want to make functionality to change product price with selected variant of product. I think with React it is better than jQuery (actual situation).

Answer (score 0):

In HTML can be

```
<div class="react-component" data="{a:1,b:1,c:[1,2,3]}"></div>
<div class="react-component" data="{a:2,b:1,c:[1,2,3]}"></div>
<div class="react-component" data="{a:3,b:1,c:[1,2,3]}"></div>
```

And in JS

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import _ from 'lodash'

const Component = (props) => {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
}

_.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName('react-component'), (element) => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Component data={element.getAttribute('data')} />, element)
})
```